# I have mistake with my jar in maven app

Tags: java, maven, jar

I have an web app with maven. This app uses a jar file to has .class (It´s other app but this jar file is not maven app, it´s done with ant, It only has .class,...).
In my web app I use classes that there are in this jar file, but when I deploy with maven install, I have the next mistake:

```
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.4:compile (default-compile) on project Web_provision: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
    [ERROR] ...\controller\common\InitialController.java:[5,59] error: package name.package... does not exist
    [ERROR]...\controller\common\InitialController.java:[20,11] error: cannot find symbol
    [ERROR] symbol:   class IWebProvisionCorporativeFacade
...
```

The jar file is into of WEB-INF/lib. But I don´t take it when I do maven install. Nevertheless in compilation time I don´t have a mistake because the web app sees this jar

This is my pom.xml

```
....  
  <dependencies>

            <!-- Spring -->

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- Tiles -->

            <dependency>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.15</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                <version>1.5.6</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
                <version>1.2</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
                <artifactId>tiles-servlet</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
                <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- Test -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>

        </dependencies>

        <build>
            <pluginManagement>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.4</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <source>${compiler.version}</source>
                            <target>${compiler.version}</target>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <argLine>-XX:-UseSplitVerifier</argLine>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </pluginManagement>
            <finalName>Web_provision</finalName>
        </build>
...
```

Comment: post your pom.xml please.

Comment: Could you show the entire `pom.xml` file and indicate which one of the dependencies contains the `secosol.alartec.core.facades.webProvision` interface ?

Comment: this inteface belows the jar file that is not a maven file, thus I cann´t do this reference.
Can I do reference to a jar file from maven file?

Comment: Yes you can reference any JAR file. It has first to be added to your local repository with install-file goal (see answer below). You can choose the artifactId/groupId/version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To reference the JAR file that contains `secosol.alartec.core.facades.webProvision`, use the [`mvn install:install-file`](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html) goal. It will install the artifact in your local repository and make it available to Maven.

You can then add it to your pom.xml in the `dependencies` section (provide the groupdId, artifactId and version). You can verify that it has been added to the dependencies of your project by calling `mvn dependency:tree`.

Comment: For my project, I had used the next:
<dependency>
         <groupId>groupId</groupId>
         <artifactId>artifactId</artifactId>
         <version>1.0</version>
         <scope>system</scope>
         <systemPath>${project.basedir}/where´s .jar file/fileName.jar</systemPath>
     </dependency>